# Parcel showing ENOENT: no such file or directory error when I save my html

Tags: package.json, parceljs, enoent

beginner web dev here, first time using parcel and sass.
So, I have the parcel set up, but when I change and save the `src/index.html`, terminal shows me [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6JtT.png), instead of changing the `dist/index.html`.

It is very weird because in the error, there is supposed to be a file called `dist/index.html.9424.5`, which really does not exist in my case.

Here is my `package.json` set up:

```
{
  "name": "calculator_project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel src/index.html",
    "build": "parcel build src/index.html"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.7.0",
    "parcel": "^2.7.0",
    "sass": "^1.55.0"
  }
}
```

Also, [this is my folder structure and html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbKbY.png)

I will be very thankful for any tips or solutions.
Also, I am very sorry if I documented this error incorrectly, I am still pretty new to this.

Thanks for reading and help!

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem, but I don't get an error.

What does your folder structure look like? Could you try to stop parcel, delete the .parcel-cache and dist folders, and restart parcel.

Comment: I edited the post so that you can see the folder structure and html

Comment: I still can't reproduce it. Did you deleted the folders I mentioned? Can you upload your code to Github and share it?

Comment: I actually got it working for few hours, but now it crashes on changing html, I will work on putting it up on github